# Passport Requirement to Rent a Car

Tags: passports, legal, car-rentals

I was surprised that an Amsterdam auto rental required a passport, despite making the reservation through Expedia.com. I have no objection to requirement: I am left wondering:

**What practical purpose (reason) does requiring the passport to rent the car serve?**

The assumption is that there is a reason/purpose for said requirement.

Fortunately, the rental company was flexible and accepted my passport card issued by the state department (not a true passport, but a National ID card), because I left the passport in the hotel safe. I **always** expect to show my driver's license when renting a car.

BTW, This is not a requirement to rent a car in the Dutch Aruba territory.

Comment: Different countries have different laws; different companies have different policies.  Are you asking why the policies differ, or are you asking for the reason behind the requirement where it exists?

Comment: As you (and every other person in the Netherlands 14 years and over) have to carry your passport or your EU national Identity card, showing it to rent a car should not be a problem at all.

Comment: @Willeke that is true, and the question even acknowledges a lack of objection to the requirement.  But it is not a violation to fail to carry ID; it is only a violation to be unable to produce it in response to an official demand.

Comment: That is hair splitting. You need to have it with you when you do certain things, like riding public transport without the right ticket, not having lights on your bike at night and many other situations, so you need to have it.

Comment: @phoog   Both, it would seem to be inconsistent (which is certainly OK as it their prerogative), but I am puzzled as to why it would not be enough to show a driver's license.  I made the reservation online through Expedia.com

Comment: We can't read the minds of the people who set the policy. Your question is unanswerable.

Comment: I had the same happen to me in Las Vegas. I think it matters to the rental car companies whether you're a local using a foreign web site to make reservation, or a true foreigner. Why? Don't know.

Comment: There is a phrase here in the UK: belt and braces.  (Suspenders in the US.)  it means taking an extra precaution.  Either a belt or braces will hold your trousers (pants) up; so both are unnecessary.  A car is an expensive item, using a belt and braces approach to verifying your identity is not unreasonable.

Comment: In short: proving one's identity using a driving license is NOT the norm in most of Europe (in countries whose citizens have ID cards). Driving license is only used to check whether someone is permitted to drive a vehicle, not to verify who they are. For example, it's not possible to open a bank account with just a driving license.

Answer (score 6):

### Verifying identity

They're handing a car to someone, and they need to verify who that person is - for liability purposes, etc.

In many European countries, a driver's license is not considered to be a valid identity document, it's explicitly legislated that identity documents are either a passport or a national ID card, and nothing else. So it makes all sense that all the company procedures state that they must request proper ID (and verify it in online registries of stolen IDs where possible), and strictly ordered to not accept any "not-a-document" substitutes as any gaps in policy would be systematically abused by fraudsters.

This is not specific to car rentals - pretty much every institution that needs to check ID will not accept drivers licenses. I don't know if Netherlands has it the same, but if my local store would want to verify my age for buying alcohol, a drivers license would not be acceptable for that - they're mandated to verify an identity document, and drivers license is legally not an identity document. However, it's worth noting that this is a relatively recent change, 5-10 years ago the penetration of ID cards was much lower and drivers licenses *were* accepted much more widely, but they are not anymore. This may explain some mismatch in expectations, as one institution may be unaware that another company has changed their policies.

It also seems plausible that they might extend the same policy to non-European customers for simplicity, and also for real risks - for example, it's nontrivial to verify the validity of all the many forms that a USA drivers license might take, documenting how you should verify USA passports seems simpler.

Comment: ‘a passport or a national ID card, and nothing else’ There are a couple of other niche forms of ID for stateless individuals or refugees but this list is pretty complete.

Comment: Your local store wouldn't even accept a driving license as proof of age? In England a driving license is almost as good as a passport.

Comment: @DavidLindon The UK doesn't have an ID card and most peaple will not be carrying a passport with them in their home country.

Comment: @DavidLindon Not if you have the old-format paper UK driver's license that lacks a photo and physical description. Those can remain valid up to 2033 if nothing changed. Hong Kong is another example, the only personal information on theirs is the name, it's supposed to be presented along with the national ID card.

Answer (score 2):

For a car rental, proof of nationality and legal status, would be needed **to prove that your driver's licence may be used**, since foreign residents, after a specific time, must exchange their driver's licence for a local one. The same rule applies in the US when moving from state to state.

As a visitor under the 90/180 days rule (entry stamp in passport) it is clear for the car rental (and any policeman stopping you while driving) that there is no problem from that aspect.

A driver's licence (or US Passport Card) is not sufficient to prove your nationality and legal status inside the Schengen Area (lack of entry stamp) by any authorized person (such as a policeman). Keeping a passport in the hotel safe is a bad idea, because if you need it you won't have it.

It also depends on the **reason** they are checking. 
While visiting the [Bundeskanzleramt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Chancellery) this summer, my friend forgot his passport, but they let him in with his Kentucky Driver's License, since they were only checking against the **nasty person's list**.

Identity checks for age by non authorized persons the Passport Card or driver's licence  should be sufficient.

This was also discussed here: [US Passport Card for Identification (not customs) purpose](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147247/us-passport-card-for-identification-not-customs-purposes)

Comment: "Keeping a passport in the hotel safe is a bad idea, because if you need it you won't have it": it is a bad idea only if the likelihood of needing it and the cost of not having it in those circumstances outweighs the likelihood of not losing it and the cost of being without it permanently.  In my experience, it is rather a very good idea to keep one's passport in the hotel safe.  Furthermore, no car rental agent has *ever* investigated passport stamps or other evidence of legal presence when examining my passport.

Comment: @phoog Be it as it may, the question was **What practical purpose (reason)** and an answer to that was given that you did not address (**proof that your driver's licence may be used**, for car rental and police). You had your passport with you, what you believe *to have **not** observed* is not a reason to downvote a valid answer.

Comment: But my passport is not used as proof that my driver's license may be used, is it?  Because I am quite certain that no use was made of my passport other than to check the biodata page.  This invariably happens right in front of my face in the space of a minute or two.   So this answer does not address the question.

Comment: @phoog You would have to ask the rental for their reasons for this requirement. For the police it **definitely** is a valid reason and therefore adrresses the question. Proof of proper identification is a requirement in most countries and that is what,  for foreigners,  a passport is for.

Comment: But this answer does not assert that the passport is being used as proof identification but rather as proof of "legal status inside the Schengen area."  And it is quite clear that rental agents do not verify that, because they check neither the stamps nor the visas in the passport.

Comment: @phoog That a car rental is **required** that the customer has a **valid** driver's licence can be assumed. Checking that a foreigner is a visitor would be part of that process. The answer addresses that with **As a visitor under the 90/180 days rule (entry stamp in passport) it is clear for the car rental (and any policeman stopping you while driving) that there is no problem from that aspect.**, which you choose to ignore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100097/discussion-between-phoog-and-mark-johnson).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a passport is required to rent a car in Aruba. All major car rental companies in Aruba require customers to present a valid passport upon pickup. This is because the passport is the primary form of identification used in Aruba, and rental companies need to verify that the customer is legally authorized to drive in the country.

Comment: The OP was trying to rent a car in Amsterdam so it is hard to see the relevance of what happens in Aruba. Can you edit to explain?

Comment: @mdewey I'm guessing because the OP says it's *not* a requirement in Aruba, as an example of why the requirement is somehow unreasonable, but this answer is saying it is actually required there.

Comment: The small company I rent from in Aruba does not require a passport.  Therefore, it is not a requirement.   My Florida driver's license is what they ask: the credit card is what they really care about.