# Turkey passport control

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, borders, turkey

I travelled from Manchester to Turkey for a week holiday. At passport control my passport was stamped then passed to another border police officer behind him who took a photo of my passport on his phone. He then asked which hotel I was staying at and asked for my phone number then sent all of these to someone on WhatsApp. He gave me my passport back and sent me on my way. I noticed he did this with a couple of other people as well.

Does anybody know why this was done?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139248/why-do-turkish-airlines-gate-agents-at-istanbul-airport-take-photos-of-passenger

Comment: something similar happened to me. The female officer took a photo of my passport cover and photo page on her phone and whatsapped to someone? Have you had anything from this? Or any issues?

Comment: Nope i never did figure out why they did it‍♂️ @JEL24